# Stored Procedures completed by me using Extended Events

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I use a SQL Server Profiler trace template called "Procs completed by me", that include this text filter: %@UserID=123%.

[image]

Almost all the stored procedures run by our website include a @UserID parameter, so I can click away and see the effect on the database. And it ignores all the stored procedures run by other website users. Incredibly useful!

How do I create the same thing in extended events?

The answer (from David below) is

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION XE_ProcsRunByMe
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed (WHERE sqlserver.like_i_sql_unicode_string(statement,N'%@UserID=123%'))
```

Comment: See [Humanevents](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_humanevents)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft like_i_sql_unicode_string seems to work. I just need to include %. Username will not work because ever website user (1000s of them) connect to the database with the same db user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the session window:
In the list on the left go to `Events`, and under `Event library:` there are the `rpc_` events.
For the user, in the same window go to `Configure` on the right, then select an actual event under `Selected events:` on the left (if you have more than one listed, as each must be set up), then on the right choose `Filter (predicate)`, and under `Field` check for the appropriate value (I can't check it now, I used to filter on my machine with `sqlserver.client_hostname` and to reduce footprint also on `sqlserver.database_name`). If the user is not the same according to SQL server user mapping, than filter on the statement instead (there should be something like `statement` in the list, but might depend on SQL server version).

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks.

This is the SQL I used:

CREATE EVENT SESSION XE_ProcsRunByMe
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed (WHERE sqlserver.like_i_sql_unicode_string(statement,N'%@UserID=123%'))